# Custom gradle task classes: is there a "post-construction" hook?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there some sort of "post-construction hook" available on custom task classes, so I can call methods like `inputs` and `outputs` in class-specific logic?

Let's say I'm defining a custom Gradle task class like

```
 class ExampleTask extends DefaultTask {
     def exFile = null
 }
```

Now, I'd like to instantiate it via

```
task('ex', type: ExampleTask) {
    exFile = file("some-example.json")
}
```

... and I'd like to automatically run the equivalent of `inputs(exFile)` on the instance.  Where does the logic go to handle this kindof configuration?  I see that I could add an `@InputFiles` decorator on a method in my custom task class, like

```
 @InputFiles
 def getFiles(){
   file(exFile)
 }
```

... but this doesn't seem very general.  I'd rather just *use* the existing `inputs()` functionality, rather than rewriting portions of it.  But I can't figure out where to call it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If necessary, you can do these initializations in the zero-argument constructor of the task class. Default property values are often set by a plugin (especially if a default value depends on information from outside the task class). Input/output annotations should be preferred over the input/output API. (The latter exists for ad-hoc tasks that don't have their own task class.)

Comment: Hmm, but the zero-argument constructor doesn't see config variables like `exFile`. (They haven't been set yet when the constructor runs...)

Comment: Such defaults need to be set by a plugin. A task class should never reach out into the project model, because this would couple it tightly to the model.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if I'm donig this wrong -- I don't want the task to reach "out into the project model." I just want it to declare *its own `exFile` parameter* (which was assigned to it explicitly at task-creation time, in the project) as an input...

Comment: I see. I guess that's one reason why the input/output annotations exist. Task classes should always use the annotations. Much cleaner than manually implementing setters that make use of the input/output API, statically discoverable, part of the documentation, etc.

Comment: OK. And is there a "friendly" resolver interface I can call from within my annotated `@InputFiles` function?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: To be clear, in your code above you'd annotate the `def exFile` property declaration itself with `@InputFile`.

Comment: Ahh. Well, my example above is a bit simplified :-) In reality I'm assigning a domain object to a property, and I can algorithmically derive input files from the properties of that domain object. So if I *do* use an `@InputFiles` function, is there a nice way to resolve files inside? Or would I just instantiate `FileTree` etc directly?

Comment: There is a generic way to refer to all input/output files of a task (`task.inputs.files`/`task.outputs.files`). For resolving files there is `project.files`, `project.fileTree`, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38447/discussion-between-bosh-and-peter-niederwieser)

Answer (score 0):

I need the exact same thing, and to my understanding, the answers are more or less - no, that is currently not possible.

See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/custom-task-with-extensions/12491